# SAS query issue on external DBMS TABLE where Column Name has space

Tags: sql-server, sas, external, space

Through SAS/ACCESS, I can successfully run data steps querying external DBMS tables. E.g.,

```
Data OutTable;
 Set ExternalDBMS.Table1;
 Where Var1 ='abc';
Run;
```

However, when column name has space, it caused a problem even I used ''n.
One example as shown below:

```
    Data OutTable;
     Set ExternalDBMS.Table1;
     Where 'Var 2'n ='abc';
    Run;

ERROR: CLI open cursor error: [SAS][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Function'.
```

Further try with SAS Option validvarname=v7 to standardize the var names with spaces still caused same error.

After using SAS Option sastrace=',,,d' I found that SAS/ACCESS submitted statement to SQL server like this:

```
SELECT   Var 1, .....
FROM  schema1.Table1
WHERE  (Var 1 ='abc' );
```

Apparently the code above would cause error in SQL server side because the Var 1 was neither quoted nor bracketed.

One way to fix it is using explicit pass-through query. I'm just wondering if there's any other ways to solve this problem too.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your second example when you used "N" it needs to be at the beggining of the string to denote a Unicode string.  putting it after is just going to give you a syntax error like your message says.  Make sure to put your schema names in brackets.  I don't know why they would have spaces in them on the database side... but i'm only familar with the SQL-side of the house.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but you are talking about the T-SQL syntax. In SAS code, I'm afraid we can't do  that. I'm trying to edit the SAS code so that SAS/ACCESS can submit right code to SQL server.

Comment: yes I apologize, I'm only familar with TSQL syntax.  In TSQL, you can use square brackets around schema names.  I assumed this might be helpful information but if I'm misunderstanding the question I apologize.

Comment: Interesting.  PROC SQL has dquote=ansi which looks like what you would want, but I don't see an analog for the DATA step or library option.  Docs seem to claim special chars are allowed using name literals, but my test errored also.  There is a PRESERVE_COLUMN_NAMES option that looks promising, but docs say that is for creating tables/columns.  Honestly, I tend to stick with explicit pass-through to avoid guessing what SAS will be able to translate.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there's still a bug in SAS/ACESS?

Answer (score 0):

when using an explicit pass-through query, put a set of square brackets around the variable name. This would be similar to how you'd write your code in SSMS.

SELECT   [Var 1], ...
FROM  schema1.Table1
WHERE  ([Var 1] ='abc' );

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow .... your question not enough quality, please read help center, section `how to ask good question` here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you can get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour